# Filter and sort through large amount of key value pairs (java)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, guava

I have a very large set of key value pairs (TBs of data), read from some files.

For simplicity, let's assume the keys and values are both integers.

In the end, I am interested in keeping each key with the highest N values it was encountered and writing them, again as key value pairs, to some different files.

There is no issue if the output file contains more than N entries for a given key, as long as the smallest 3 values are among them.

Keeping the files as they are satisfies the above condition, but I'm trying to reduce the size, since some keys have lots of values in the input, which are not of interest.

Keeping all the data in memory is clearly not an option.

Thus I'm looking for some kind of cache. Something where I can keep a sorted list for each key I find, and once a specific size limit is reached, I'd just flush half of the entries from the cache to the output. Guava's `LoadingCache` does not seem to help me here, because the weights are `computed at entry creation time, and are static thereafter.`

Is there a specific data structure/algorithm I can use/implement that may help me here?

Comment: There are implementations of the [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface, such as [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which seems fitting keeping in mind that your requirements still need processing apart from the data structure the data is kept it.

Comment: Weights are at creation or update time, though an update to the value is probably best done via a `Map.compute` - where Caffeine's is more robust. I guess you would use a `SortedSet` value, as a `Multimap`-like cache. If the files are local, then I/O can be very fast to favor multiple passes (e.g sort and filter or map/shuffle/reduce).

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach:

1. Sort the original file Your sorting criteria is key in ascending order, value in descending order. The Linux `sort` utility makes quick work of this. (Well, quick as in it's quick to type the command. Sorting terabytes of data will take some time.)
2. Write a program that goes through the file sequentially and saves the top N values.

You're all done.

If the data is spread across multiple files, where values for a particular key can be in more than one file, then you sort each file individually and then merge the multiple files together. Again, `sort` can do this for you.

I can't guarantee that the above will execute faster than a custom solution, but I'm pretty confident in saying that it will execute faster than you can design, code, debug, test, and then run your custom solution.